# Velocidad aleatoria en hilos Java

Tags: java, hilos, random

Tengo hecho un pequeño programa simulando una carrera con tres hilos. Mi idea es poner dichas velocidades con numero randoms para que el resultado varíe, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Código:

```
public class Carrera extends Thread
{
    String nombre;
    int velocidad;

    public Carrera(String nombre,int velocidad) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(nombre+" ");
            try {
                sleep(1000/velocidad);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        System.out.println("Terminó: "+nombre);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Carrera friki1 = new Carrera("f1", 4);
        Carrera friki2 = new Carrera("f2", 3);
        Carrera friki3 = new Carrera("f3", 1);

        friki1.start();
        friki2.start();
        friki3.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Carrera friki1 = new Carrera("f1", random.nextInt(10));
    Carrera friki2 = new Carrera("f2", random.nextInt(10));
    Carrera friki3 = new Carrera("f3", random.nextInt(10));

    friki1.start();
    friki2.start();
    friki3.start();
}
```